# Working with PHP in Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I have an Eclipse project with mostly PHP files.

I installed the PHPeclipse plugin, restarted Eclipse, and switched to the PHP perspective.

Now I see a PHP icon next to the PHP files in the Project Explorer.

But, when I click the files, they are still opened in gedit (the default text editor) and not in Eclipse.

Additionally, when I drag the files towards the Eclipse editor, they are opened as plain text (without context highlighting).

I can right-click any file, select "Open With", and select the "PHP Editor". But this is cumbersome as I have a lot of files.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: which Linux are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Change the default editor for PHP files. This can be done: 
Window->Preferneces->General->Editor->File Associations. You can select the default editor for different files right there.

Comment: I suppose the OP is using a Gnome flavored Linux.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu you can just right-click a particular file then open Properties. Then go to the open with tab, choose your program and set it as default.